# How to configure SFML in CodeBlocks and install the required files and prerequisites?

Tags: codeblocks, sfml

I tried following the  given tutorial on SFML official website: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-cb.php and am struggling with installing SFML on CodeBlocks. 
I am getting the message: **sfml-grapfics-2.dll is not on your computer.**, although the file is already inside the bin folder of sfml. I want to figure out what is the actual issue and how to resolve it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason your SFML path includes "21"? Are you using an outdated version of SFML?

Comment: go to the settings -> compiler -> toolchain executables tab -> additional paths tab then add the location of sfml bin folder there. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're given is due to Windows not finding the library file when trying to run/debug the program. It has nothing to do with your compiler/IDE settings directly.

I'm not familiar with Code Blocks and there might be an option for binary directories somewhere, but the easiest fix for this is simply copying the missing DLLs from SFML's bin directory to the location where your built executable is sitting.

As a alternative, add `C:\sfml21\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable so it's found by the system. Although keep in mind that you'll still have to package/ship these libraries together with your compiled program, so I'd recommend the other option above.

As a third option, download the SFML sources and compile them from scratch as a static library. This way you won't need any additional DLL files (except OpenAL32.dll due to licensing).